# prevent jsf validation message for printing on console

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

jsf validation gives this massage

> INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.renderkit] WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed. sourceId=null[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(Your User Name or Password is incorrect.), detail=(Your User Name or Password is incorrect.)]

But my `login.xhtml` page shows `Your User Name or Password is incorrect.` massage. what is wrong with this.

**EDIT**: **I wanted to prevent printing this massage in console**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
In case you want message to not to be printed in logs... turn off the logging for `javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.renderkit`. I believe you are using `log4j`. We have turned it off with following entry in your **`jboss-log4j.xml`**:

```
<category name="javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.renderkit">
    <priority value="OFF" />
</category>
```

If it's not `log4j` It depends on what logging library you are using. Try setting the
default logging level to ERROR or FATAL. Otherwise, just set the logging level for `javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.renderkit` to something higher than INFO.

So it is this **other** logging library that you need to configure in order to control what gets output.

If your `WEB-INF/lib` directory contains `log4j.jar`, then you will need to add a `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml` file into your `WEB-INF/classes` dir to configure log4j. See the log4j project for further instructions.

If your `WEB-INF/lib` directory does not contain `log4j.jar` then this is probably being logged via the `java.util.logging` implementation provided in the java standard libraries. So you will need to configure that; see the javadoc for the `java.util.logging` classes for details.

Hope this gives you enough information.

Comment: I wanted to prevent printing this massage in console

Comment: i don't use any logging mechanism in my project. I think this is some thing else

Comment: What is the jsf version and application server you are using?

Comment: I am using jsf2 and jboss 6.0